# JHipster entity have user property set to null when serialized in JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jhipster

I'm not a huge expert of Spring Boot, and a beginner with JHipster

My entity is :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
public class Meal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) // added this to JHipster generation
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("meals")
    private User user;

    // ...
}
```

I don't think the fetch eager is needed, as it's eager by default I guess. I also tried with or without `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

I didn't touch the `GET /api/meals` resource

```java
    @GetMapping("/meals")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Meal>> getAllMeals(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        Page<Meal> page = mealService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(uriBuilder.queryParams(queryParams), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

nor service:

```java
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Meal> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Meals");
        return mealRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

And I get this JSON:

```js
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "instant" : "2019-06-20T03:59:53Z",
  "user" : null
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "instant" : "2019-06-20T04:18:47Z",
  "user" : null
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the database file `meals.csv` loaded by liquibase had no `user` column.

I've update the `meals.csv` file

```
id;instant;text;user_id
1;2019-06-20T03:59:53;My own value;4
2;2019-06-20T04:18:47;And another meal;4
```

Updated manually the changeset by finding `loadData` (might not be the best practice !)

```xml
<changeSet id="20190620074431-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
        <loadData
                  file="config/liquibase/data/meal.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="meal">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="instant" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="text" type="string"/>
            <column name="user_id" type="numeric"/> <!-- <<< Added this -->
        </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

then ran `./mvnw clean` and relaunched the app.

This worked for me and seems logical but I wonder why foreign keys are not randomly generated.

Comment: The CSV are just fake data for dev profile, there are currently some discussions about it in github, feel free to propose and maybe contribute a new feature.